# Shared preferences not working as expected

Tags: android

Below is my code to the MainActivity.java of my project, this is the welcome like screen for my app and should only appear first time user opens the app. Otherwise the user should get to see the Medicine_Activity.java which is also triggered when the user presses "Get Started" button on MainActivity. In order to implement this i came across something known as SharedPreferences and tried to implement it. But it isnt working quite as expected, the MainActivity flashes for a second before Medicine_Activity is launched. I am new so please help me out

Here is a video clip to view this bug in action - https://www.dropbox.com/s/fqbo9urb6xnh3pd/WhatsApp%20Video%202019-06-20%20at%202.12.50%20PM.mp4?dl=0

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btnGetStarted;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        boolean previouslyStarted = prefs.getBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_previously_started), false);
        if(!previouslyStarted) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
            edit.putBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_previously_started), Boolean.TRUE);
            edit.apply();
        } else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Medicine_Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //will hide the title
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); // hide the title bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //enable full screen
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btnGetStarted = findViewById(R.id.btnGetStarted);
        btnGetStarted.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Medicine_Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `commit()` while storing the `true` and `finish()` the `MainActivity`.

```
if(!previouslyStarted) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
    edit.putBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_previously_started), true);
    edit.commit();
} else{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Medicine_Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

A short explanation: `commit()` writes the data synchronously (blocking the thread its called from). It then informs you about the success of the operation. However, `apply()` schedules the data to be written asynchronously. It does not inform you about the success of the operation.

Quoting from [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()):

> Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to disk and you won't be notified of any failures